Cant find Ubuntu on my dualboot
I have a computer with 2 hard drives. One has Windows installed on it. Now, I thought I would install Ubuntu on the other one. I chose the second one because it has significantly more space available. So, I partitioned it (see attachment). I freed up about 200 GB. When I booted into the Ubuntu installation using a USB flash drive, I was able to select where I wanted to install Linux. Everything worked fine up to this point. However, I mistakenly used another partition (this 14MB one) on disk 1 for the boot loader installation, and I defined it as the boot medium. Now, I can't find this boot medium anywhere and I can't start Linux. I am dont know what too do any more, i watched multiple videos and searched a lot. I think its because of the location of the boot loader.
Ubuntu is located in "Datenträger 1" and the partition with 200gb. And the boot loader in the 16mb.

Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair &
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

fixed the problem by giving it a bigger partition and selected another partition for grub
